# Removing a row from table based on the <td> id using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the following table.
    `<table>
        <tr>
            <td id="cat1"> cat </td>
            <td id="dog1"> dog </td>
            <td id="hen1">hen </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cat2"> cat </td>
            <td id="dog2"> dog </td>
            <td id="hen2">hen </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cat3"> cat </td>
            <td id="dog3"> dog </td>
            <td id="hen3">hen </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cat4"> cat </td>
            <td id="dog4"> dog </td>
            <td id="hen4">hen </td>
        </tr>
    </table>`

I need to remove the rows based on  tag 'ID' from the above table.
Is there any best way tp do so using JavaScript.

Comment: @TonyBarnes the code was supplied, just a formatting issue

Comment: Do you need to remove the entire `<tr>...</tr>` based on a `td`'s id? Or just the individual `<td>...</td>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use vanilla javascript and remove the parent node of the `<td>`. For example;

```js
document.getElementById("dog4").parentNode.remove();
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="cat1"> cat </td>
        <td id="dog1"> dog </td>
        <td id="hen1">hen </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cat2"> cat </td>
        <td id="dog2"> dog </td>
        <td id="hen2">hen </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cat3"> cat </td>
        <td id="dog3"> dog </td>
        <td id="hen3">hen </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cat4"> cat </td>
        <td id="dog4"> dog </td>
        <td id="hen4">hen </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will delete the entire `<tr>` which has a child with `id=dog4`.

#### [JSfiddle mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/sniko/9kzrs400/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the jquery function.

Removes all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
$("#ID").empty();
```

or

Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
$("#ID").remove();
```

Comment: Bit of an overkill to use jQuery for this.

Comment: He will still use jquery in the near future :)

Comment: @RexAdrivan Not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.remove()` jQuery method as shown :-

```
$("table tr td#ID").remove();
```

Or you can use `.empty()` method as shown :-

```
$("table tr td#ID").empty();
```

- `empty()` will remove all the contents of the selection.
- `remove()` will remove the selection and its contents.